# Alternative to procedural loop with evaluation of notebooks

Tags: performance-tuning, procedural-programming

very new Mathematica user here. I am struggeling with programming Mathematical-like and would appreciate some guidance.

I set up a main notebook which calls various sub-notebooks:

```
 EvaluateNB := NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "filename.nb"}]];
```

These sub-notebooks contain just basic calculations.

I then want to set up a loop to find the number of iterations until some conditions aren't met anymore. So far it looks like this:

```
iterations = 0;
data = Range

While[  
  (*test*)
    KI < Kmat
    && a < 0.8*t
    && If[typ1 == 2, a < 2*c, 1 == 1]
    && Sf >= 1,
  (*increment*)
    iterations++;
  (*function*)
    Krn = Krf;
    Lrn = Lrf;  
    EvaluateVar;
    (*min*) 
    p = pmin; 
    EvaluateG;
    EvaluateK;
    Kmin = KI;
    (*max.*)
    p = pmax;
    EvaluateG;
    EvaluateK;
    EvaluateSref;
    Kmax = KI;
    (*calculations*)
    ΔK = Kmax - Kmin;
    R = Kmin/Kmax;
    an = a + dadN[ΔK]*dN;
    cn = c + dadN[ΔK]*dN;
    a = an;
    c = cn;
    atf = a/t;
    acf = a/c;
    Krf = KI/Kmat;
    Lrf = σref/sy;
    EvaluateFAD2;
    AppendTo[pa, a];
    AppendTo[pKmin, Kmin];
    AppendTo[pKmax, Kmax];
    AppendTo[pΔK, ΔK];
    AppendTo[pσref, σref];
  ];
```

What it does is basically setting new variables (e.g. p=pmin, since p is later used in EvaluateK, EvaluateSref, etc.), calling the notebooks to get their output to then write these outputs to a list for later visualizations.
Once the conditions are not fulfilled, the loop stops and I get the number of iterations plus the output in tables.

Problem is, for small amounts of iterations it is fast enough but once the input parameters cause lots of iterations it takes a lot of time to end this loop.

I've read there are more elegant ways to set up a loop and write output to a list. But a google search didn't lead meaningful results (at least for me).

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You should use Reap and Sow instead of AppendTo. For example, you could `results=Reap[While[...loop body here... Sow[{a, Kmin, Kmax, \[CapitalDelta]K, \[Sigma]ref}]][[2,1]]` then join them onto the other lists once the loop is over with `{pa, pKmin, pKmax, p\[CapitalDelta]K, p\[Sigma]ref} = 
 Thread[Join[{pa, pKmin, pKmax, p\[CapitalDelta]K, p\[Sigma]ref}, 
   Transpose@results]]`

Comment: Also, you'd be better off loading the notebooks once and calling functions defined in them, than repeatedly loading notebooks in a loop. Perhaps Mathematica caches stuff and it's fast enough for you, but I would never write it that way myself.